# Scrollable container inside a CSS Grid not working on mobile (Safari and Chrome, but works in Chrome DevTools in mobile mode)

Tags: css, mobile, scroll, css-grid

I'm having trouble with a container that is not scrollable on mobile devices (iPhone) on both Safari and Chrome (both are up-to-date, but I'm still on iOS 14).

Here is the issue in action:
http://fruityfred.com/dev/scroll/

On a desktop browser, the blue container is scrollable (with beautiful and very clever content ;) ), even when DevTools is in mobile mode. But on my iPhone (and the ones of my coworkers), the same container is not scrollable. Tested on both Safari and Chrome, and it gives me the same result: no scrolling.

Do you have an idea of how I could fix that?

Comment: I cannot test this, but looking at your code. I would guess it is the conflict between the two overflows you have. I would remove it completely from ".page .content > div > div" and see if it resolves it.

Comment: Well, after a few other tests and searches on the web, it seems that there is a bug when handling relative units (fr, %) in CSS Grids on iOS. So I guess this is the origin of my problem.